# best way to display location an image is associated with on mobile

Tags: mobile, maps

I've been asked to come up with an interaction for a list on a mobile. The list is a set of ten repeating items: image and paragraph. Each listing item has a location associated with it.

[image]

**My question:**
Is there a precedent for this kind of interaction "I need to view the location of a thing in a list"?

My initial thoughts are to have a map icon launch a map that overlays the image.

Comment: How is the location entered in the system? Is it just the name of the city or complete building address? Either way, I think displaying at least the City or Street/Locality name should be helpful for the users, depending on the context. If I were looking for a shop, the streets nearby would matter more than the city. Then, I would tap on the location icon to check its actual location which would preferably let me choose my choice of map application.

Comment: it's the location in the country. An example might be 'London' and then a map of great britain with london highlighted

Answer (score 0):

I saw something called [Sparkmaps](https://www.mapuipatterns.com/sparkmaps/) that you might be interested in on the Map UI Patterns website.

It is based on the same principle as [Sparklines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline), which provides a compact way to display a series or array of information condensed into a small space.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it heavily depends on the *why*. **Why does the user need to see the location associated with an image?**

1. Is it a list of restaurants, the user picks one and then wants to go there? *Put a little arrow icon and redirect to a maps application*
2. Is the point to build up a mental model of geographical relations, such as in a learning app about Napoleon's military campaign? *It may be useful to put the images on the map, instead of the map on the images.*
3. Is it the location where the user took the photo? *A little tag in the corner saying "Verona, Italy" is sufficient — and you probably don't want to a map overlay, you probably want to filter the photos by this location or something*.
4. Is it just a little extra information, like author or views, to make the UI feel more dynamic, more alive? *See how other apps in your space handle this*.
5. Is how the map looks actually integral, because you are showing how old city centers in the Balkans look and feel? *Consider showing the actual map in 2cm x 2cm tile*.

...I can think of endless possibilities. **Define what the user actually wants (larger goal), then enable her to do it as conveniently as possibly.**